# Gitbook not linking to root directory

Tags: anchor, gitbook

In my markdown in gitbook, I have a link from a file in one folder to another page in a different folder:

in /folder2/file.md:

`![](/example-folder/example-file.html#example-link)`

In the gitbook editor's live preview, this link works as expected and goes to the correct page and location.

In the command line gitbook build, however, the html generated drops the initial slash and results in the html:

`<a href="example-folder/example-file.html#example-link">`
Without the initial slash, the link is no longer pointing to the root directory where the desired file is, and instead is trying to find /folder2/example-folder/

I have tried using a `./` at the beginning of the path, and get the same result.

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any updates?